# Status de venda em C#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou criando um sistema de locação de automóveis em C# e gostaria de implementar uma função que me retorna todos os carros e uma coluna que mostra se o carro solicitado está locado ou não, se estiver locado, a bolinha seria verde e senão, a bolinha vermelha e isso mudasse automaticamente ao fazer a locação. Já pesquisei em diversos lugares mais não encontro, Segue abaixo um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A consulta eu consigo fazer, o problema é essa variavel STATUS

Comment: É necessário que você mostre o que você já tem feito, falta código, exemplo, estrutura de dados, código interface, seja mais limitado

Comment: Preciso de mais detalhes amigo. De onde você obtêm essa informação e em qual tipo de GUI você pretende apresentar estás informações?

Answer (score -1):

Há vários meios de se fazer essa verificação, por exemplo, usando 0 para indisponivel e 1 para disponivel, criar uma função que muda o status dessa variavel para o carro alugado de 0 para 1. Depois basta adicionar esse valor na tabela que montou de status.

Também pode usar a lib `bool` que se baseia no mesmo principio, só que usando `true` e `false`.Exemplo:

```
#include<stdbool.h>

bool setStatus(carro){
    if(carro == Alugado){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```